# Measure of the behavior of Swaption surface

Tags: volatility, interest-rates, swaption, numerical-methods

I'm looking to find a different measure than average shift move to explain the behavior of the IR VOL products say Swaption. I know it's a very open question not only touching upon IR VOL scope.
Let me give you an example.

Say I have a Swaption surface which can be described in the matrix form for two random days and a few random tenors.

[image]

Now, I will calculate the shifts between 09th and 10th as a difference. The resulting shifts matrix looks like:

[image]

Taking average of all that numbers I end up with the result being 0.0109772873570582. Thus the average move would be approx. 0.01.

1. What disadvantages you think this method might have?
2. Are there any alternative methods to describe the behavior of that surface different than the one explained above?

Comment: You may want to look into PCA: 
https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2002.00085 , https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-4919-9_14 ,  https://doi.org/10.1023/B:REDR.0000004823.77464.2d . Also for swaptions it is better to have 3 dimentions: the time to expiry of the options, the time to the maturity of the underlting swaps, and also the moneyness.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look. Very interesting

Comment: PCA can be difficult to apply if you don't consider the units. If your units are percent vols then the underlying forward rates on which your percent vols apply are also relevant. It may be better start to convert to normal bp vols which are standardised units before proceeding.